# prove limit of function by definition

Tags: calculus

Let $a\in\mathbb R $. Assume that:
$$
\lim _{x\to a} \left ( f(x) +\frac{1}{|f(x)|}  \right ) = 0
$$
Find $\lim _{x\to a} f(x) $ and prove by definition that it is the limit.
I am guessing that the limit is $-1$ but I have difficulty to show that. Any suggestions? Thanks for helpers!

Comment: Say $L$ is the limit of $f(x)$. Then what would the limit of $f(x)+1/|f(x)|$ be?

Comment: -1. Do you have any suggestion how to prove it?

Comment: ??? Read my question again - you're answering something totally different.

Comment: $L+1/|L|$ am I right?

Comment: Right. So you just have to show that if $L+1/|L|=0$ then $L=-1$. (Two possibilities: (i) $L+1/L=0$ and $L>0$, (ii) $L-1/L=0$ and $L<0$.)

Comment: This is what I wrote in the question

Comment: ????????????????

Comment: I believe Shlomi already used a method like this to see that if the limit exists, it must be -1. What he seems to want is a delta-epsilon style proof that shows it actually is the limit or would at least show $f$ must have a limit as $x\to a$.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the function $\phi(t) = t + {1 \over |t|}$.

Note that if $t >0$ then $\phi(t) \ge 2$.

Note that $\lim_{t \to 0} \phi(t) = \infty$.

In particular, note that $\phi(t) \le {3 \over 2}$ **iff** $t \le -{1 \over 2}$.

Note that when restricted to $(-\infty,-{1 \over 2}]$, $\phi$ is invertible and the inverse $\eta = \phi^{-1}$ is continuous.

Note that if $y \le {3 \over 2}$ and $\phi(t) = y$, then we must have $t \le -{1 \over 2}$. Hence $\phi(t) = t -{1 \over t} = y$ and
multiplying across by $t$ gives the equation $t^2-t y -1 = 0$ and
hence $t = { 1\over 2} (y-\sqrt{y^2+4})$. Hence $\eta(y) = { 1\over 2} (y-\sqrt{y^2+4})$, which is continuous.

You are given that $\lim_{x \to a} \phi(f(x)) = 0$, in particular,
for some $\delta>0$ we have $\phi(f(x)) < {3 \over 2}$
for all $x \in B(a,\delta)$ and so $f(x) < -{1 \over 2}$ for all
$x \in B(a,\delta)$. (In particular, for $x \in B(a,\delta)$, we have $\eta(\phi(f(x))) = f(x)$).

Since $\eta$ is continuous at $0$ we have
$$-1 = \eta(0) = \eta(\lim_{x \to a} \phi(f(x))) = \lim_{x \to a} \eta(\phi(f(x))) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$$

Comment: How does it help? I cannot use the rule of chain because I do not know that f(x) converges when $x\to a$

Comment: I am thinking about what you are writinig but I cannot figure out how does it help to the original question. Can you give me some insight?

Comment: @Shlomi: I added a complete answer.

Comment: Thanks! one more question: Why $\eta$ is continuous at $0$?

Comment: and also I see that you assume that $$f(x) >0 $$ for some $ \delta$. can you clarify it?

Comment: @Shlomi: I don't see where I assume $f(x) >0$?

Comment: because you have absolute value in the question so the given limit is not $\phi (f(x)) $

Comment: @Shlomi: My apologies, I mean to have the $|t|$ in the definition of $\phi$. Will correct...

Comment: @Shlomi: The general gist of my answer is that the question is really about the behaviour of the function $t \mapsto t+{1 \over |t|}$.